# CSS or JQuery responsive 'image fill div' with a catch

Tags: jquery, css, image, resize

I am trying to replicate a very neat method of resizing images and filling a div for responsive design. Basically, the following happens.

1. On resize, images resize to perfectly fill the parent div while maintaining equal margin between each image.
2. Once div gets too small, images overflow (as one does with block display and float left)
3. HERE IS THE MAGIC: On overflow of images, all images again resize to fill div, and this repeats for perfect image placement in parent div, with least amount of space wastage.

Here follows an example if my explanation is hard to understand:

[Example](https://www.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/seasons-and-holidays?include_editorial=false&offset=0&page=1)

Regards, 
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVWpvO

html

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
```

css

```
body {text-align: center;}
img {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  img {width: 30%;}
}
@media (max-width: 980px) {
  img {width: 45%;}
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  img {width: 70%;}
}
```

or css using calc();

```
body {text-align: center; margin: 0;}
img {
  margin: 10px;
  width: calc(100%/4 - 4*6px);
}
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  img {width: calc(100%/3 - 3*8px);}
}
@media (max-width: 980px) {
  img {width: calc(100%/2 - 2*11px);}
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  img {width: calc(100%);}
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXBZPL

Comment: This is very close. The only difference is that this version does not maintain the same margin width on the sides of the div containing the images. If you look at the example, the margins around the images never change. Some way image size is recalculated to perfectly fit any dimension (and device width).

Comment: OMG that is perfect! You nailed it, sir!